# store.fetch is not a function (dojo)

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I am trying to implement a `filteringselect(dojo)` I am trying to get the values from a memory store. I am able to see the `filteringselect` on my page but it is not returning any thing and firebug keeps saying that **`store.fetch is not a function`**

Below is the code snippet. Any clues?

```
store1 = new dojo.store.Memory({data: fArr});
   var f1 = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
                    name: "Ans",
                    searchAttr: "No",
                    placeHolder: "Select",
                    store: store1
                }, "filteringSelect");
        f1 .placeAt("s1");
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store:`dojo.data.ObjectStore({ objectStore:store1})` this worked for me..

Answer (score 5):

dojo.store.Memory uses the new store API, while FilteringSelect is trying to access it with the old API (fetch).

You can try to use the dojo.store.DataStore adapter in order to pass a new style store to something that expects the old interface.

```
new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    //...
    store: dojo.store.DataStore(store1)
});
```

Comment: You can mark answers by clicking on the green checkmark to "officially" say the solution worked for you.

Comment: +1 for the answer, hope you get your official solution mark :)